# Stop Entity Frameworks from refreshing identity field?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have scenario where I create/insert records using Entity Frameworks but I don't care about state after save operation completed - web service enviroment.

Typical trace on SQL Server side:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Log]([CreatedOn], [DeviceKey], [DeviceTime], [Message], [Source], [StackTrace], [Category], [Priority])
values (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7)
select [LogKey]
from [dbo].[Log]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [LogKey] = scope_identity()',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 int,@2 datetime2(7),@3 varchar(250),@4 varchar(250),@5 varchar(max) ,@6 tinyint,@7 tinyint',@0='2012-08-30 21:43:16.6633154',@1=6,@2='2012-08-30 21:43:14.4310000',@3='Test 2',@4='',@5='Somewhere',@6=0,@7=3
```

EF inserts part `select [LogKey] from dbo.Log where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and LogKey = scope_identity()`

I don't really want this code to run. Is it possible to stop EF doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using database generated keys (identity columns) it is not possible to avoid this. EF needs the autogenerated ID back as part of its insert logic.